# Return true, return false when using switch

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a switch to return true or false, but I seem to be failing somewhere. I keep getting false. I'm totally lost. This should have worked actually. How do I get this right?

```
if (validNum(1))
{echo 'Ok';}else{echo 'Fail';}

function validNum($x)
{
switch ($x)
{
case 1:
  echo "Number 1";
  break;
  return true;

case 2:
  echo "Number 2";
  break;
  return true;
case 3:
  echo "Number 3";
  break;
  return true;

default:
  echo "No number between 1 and 3";
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: [break ends execution of the current switch structure.](http://php.net/break)

Comment: how it will return if you are breaking the case before return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rewrite it to below. It merges three cases together and avoids using a `break` statement that would otherwise go past your `switch`. Basically, with `return` you don't need `break`.

```
switch ($x)
{
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
    echo "Number $x";
    return true;

  default:
    echo "No number between 1 and 3";
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `break` is that it jumps out of the `case`. You're never reaching your `return` statements. You never need to both `return` *and* `break` from within a case.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting a `break` in front of your `return`.  It will never hit the `return`.

Comment: Ok. So I put the return before the break. It works ok. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: No, remove the break completely. You don't *need* a break if you're using a return.